# How do I stretch my resolution on xbox one for Fortnite?

Tags: xbox-one, fortnite-battle-royale

Recently, I have been attempting to stretch my resolution on Fortnite Battle Royale, but I do not seem able to do it. I know it is in the settings somewhere, and I have tried to look for it. Does anybody know where the setting is, and how to get to it?

Comment: How do you "know it is in the settings somewhere"?

Comment: Because I have looked in the Fortnite settings in game, and it is not there. Also, people have told me that it is in settings, and I tried to follow a prompt to stretch my res, and it told me to go to settings. ( It did not work )

Comment: Could you also clarify what you mean by "stretch my resolution"? Do you mean field of view, your TV's resolution, force a specific aspect ratio, etc.?

Comment: Why would you want to right now? The stretched resolution is terrible nowadays and you can't play any competitive.

Comment: How is it terrible if almost every streamer uses it.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to use your TV remote. There will be a button labelled something along the lines of DISPLAY. Press it until it shows you the 'Screen Fit' option. I was having the same problem and this is the easiest way to fix it on a Samsung TV. I am not sure about other brands and only have personal experience using this method on Samsung.

Comment: I currently have an old LG TV, that is about 8 or so years old.

Answer (score 0):

Open the Xbox Guide,
go to Settings
Under Display and Sound, select Video Output, then
select whatever display and resolution you want.